# Construct a topological space

Tags: general-topology

> For an infinite topological space $X$, is there a way to construct a
> new space $Y$ such that $X \subsetneq Y$ (i.e., $\exists \ i: X \rightarrow Y$, an embedding not surjective) and $X \simeq Y$
> (homeomorphic)?

Comment: If $X \subset Y$ means the set $X$ is contained in the set $Y$ then the answer is yes. If  $X \subset Y$ means that $Y$ contains a homeomorphic copy of $X$ then the answer is no. Please specify.

Comment: @Daron Can you elaborate on why there might not be a space $Y$? What's an example of a space $X$ such that no homotopy equivalent space contains it as a homeomorphic copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, if $X$ has only finitely many points, then if $X\subsetneq Y$ then $Y$ must have more points than $X$, so $X$ cannot be homeomorphic to $Y$.

For an infinite counterexample, consider $X=S^1$.  If $X\subsetneq Y$ and $X\simeq Y$, that means that there is a proper subset of $X$ that is homeomorphic to $X$ (namely, the preimage of $X\subset Y$ under a homeomorphism $X\to Y$).  But no such subset exists, since every connected proper subset of $X$ is an interval.

Comment: What about in the infinite case. It's pretty obvious that the question has an affirmative "no" when considering the case (as you have shown).

Comment: @Eric Well, you are right. But I mean when X is not finite. I'll change the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the circle. Assume $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is an embedding. Then its degree has to be $\pm 1$ (by a local argument), and therefore it's surjective.